# Unknown MySQL server host 'http://sql9.000webhost.com/phpMyAdmin/index.php?db=a7026992_poslaju&lang=en-utf-8&token=f5bbef5c97a6' (3)

Tags: php, database-connection

This is my config.inc.php as below,

```
<?php

$mysql_host = "http://sql9.000webhost.com/phpMyAdmin/index.php?db=a7026992_poslaju&lang=en-utf-8&token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$mysql_dbname = "dbName";
$mysql_username = "userName";  
$mysql_password = "passWord";

$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');
try
{
$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$mysql_host};port=3306;dbname={$mysql_dbname};charset=utf8", $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $options);
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    function undo_magic_quotes_gpc(&$array)
    {
        foreach($array as &$value)
        {
            if(is_array($value))
            {
                undo_magic_quotes_gpc($value);
            }
            else
            {
                $value = stripslashes($value);
            }
        }
    }
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_POST);
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_GET);
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_COOKIE);
}
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
session_start();

?>
```

This full error message is as below,
Failed to connect to the database: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'http://sql9.000webhost.com/phpMyAdmin/index.php?db=DBDBDB&lang=en-utf-8&token=XXXXXXXXXXX' (3)

Comment: @Zouzou any help here?

Comment: If I missed out any information need to be given please tell me. @chrkad

Comment: I change my coding up there the new error pop out..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try out lging in via command line???
Check if mysql is set in `path` variable...
Then Try: 
`START->RUN->CMD`
`mysql -u <username> -p`

and check log-in status...
Please check mysql services are running at OS background or not.

Thanks.